# Trying to read a txt file of multiple matrices and store as multiple arrays

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, readfile

I am trying to take a .txt file which holds multiple matrices, and then store each matrix as an array. I am starting with just 2, and can work my way up from there.

I have a feeling there is just a tiny thing wrong with my logic but I can't seem to get it right to sort the 2 arrays separately.

If anyone has any suggestions or advice that would be greatly appreciated thank you!

Here is my code for it so far:

```
A = []
B = []
f = open("matrix.txt")

while True:
    line = f.readline()
    if not line:   #if end of file is reached, close
        print("end of file has been reached")
        break
    if line == '\n':  #when there is a blank line
        f.readline()
        if not line:  # if end of file is reached, close
            print("end of file has been reached")
            break
        else:
            B.append(list(map(int, line.split())))
        np.array(B)
    else:
        A.append(list(map(int, line.split())))
    np.array(A)
print("Matrix A")
print(A)
print("Matrix B")
print(B)
```

Comment: You aren’t saving np.array(B) in a variable. Same applies for A. Currently it’s not clear from your question what is the problem you’re Encountering

Answer (score 0):

Think again over what you're doing. Every line of the file is processed individually; if the line is empty (that is, if it consists of just a newline character), you append to `B`. Otherwise, you append to `A`. You can see that this is completely independent of whether or not you have *already* hit a newline character. A better way to go about it would be this:

```
A, B = [], []
f = open("matrix.txt")

line = f.readline()
# first, handle reading in matrix A.
while len(line.strip()) != 0:  # detects any whitespace-filled line
    A.append(list(map(int, line.split())))
    line = f.readline()
array_A = np.array(A)

# Now, after encountering a blank line, handle matrix B the same way
line = f.readline()
while len(line.strip()) != 0:
    B.append(list(map(int, line.split())))
    line = f.readline()
array_B = np.array(B)

# ...and so on
```

Comment: You're definitely right about my logic, thank you for pointing that out to me. When I try and run your code, both the arrays print blank. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: I fixed it! I just needed to set the len(line.strip()) != 0: